# Get all order in shoplify API

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-api-node

I am trying it fetch all orders from the specific date range in Shopify. The problem is I am only able to get 250 orders.  I am using the following code.

```
<div id="main-content1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php
            function nextorders($lastorderno,$orderfm,$orderto,$orders) {
                $orders_obj_url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/orders.json&since_id='.$lastorderno.'&status=any&created_at_min='.$orderfm.'T00:00:00&created_at_max='.$orderto.'T23:59:59&fields=created_at,id,order_status_url,total_price_set,number,note,note_attributes';
                $orders_content = @file_get_contents( $orders_obj_url );
                $orders_json = json_decode( $orders_content, true );
                $orders_new = $orders_json['orders'];
                $orders = $orders_json['orders'];
                if ($remaningprder > 0) {
                    $lastorderno = $orders['0']["number"];                    
                    nextorders($lastorderno,$orderfm,$orderto,$orders_new);
                }
                return $orders_new;
            }
            if ($_POST) {
                $orderfm = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['start']));
                $orderto = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['end']));
                $orders_obj_url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/orders.json?limit=250&fields=created_at,id,order_status_url,total_price_set,number,note,note_attributes&status=any&created_at_min='.$orderfm.'T00:00:00&created_at_max='.$orderto.'T23:59:59';
                $orders_content = @file_get_contents( $orders_obj_url );
                $orders_json = json_decode( $orders_content, true );
                $orders = $orders_json['orders'];
                if (count($orders) > 249) {
                    $remaningprder = $total_order - count($orders);
                    $lastorderno = $orders['0']["number"];
                    $orders = nextorders($lastorderno,$orderfm,$orderto,$orders);
                }
            }
        ?> 

        <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="offset-lg-3 offset-md-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="offset-lg-3 offset-md-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <label>Date Range</label>                                    
                        <div class="input-daterange input-group" data-provide="datepicker">
                            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" value="<?=$startset;?>" name="start" autocomplete="off">
                            <span class="input-group-addon range-to">to</span>
                            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" value="<?=$endset; ?>" name="end" autocomplete="off">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>Last order</h2>
                        <ul class="header-dropdown dropdown">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="full-screen"><i class="icon-frame"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <div class="table-responsive hide-table">
                            <?php if (count($orders) > 0) { ?>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Order No</th>
                                        <th>Amount</th>
                                        <th>Token</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                      $i=1; 
                                      foreach ($orders as $order) { 
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th scope="row" data-title="Date"><?=$i++;?></th>
                                      <td data-title="Order No"><a href="<?=$order["order_status_url"];?>" target="_blank"><?=$order["number"];?></a></td>
                                      <td data-title="Amount"><?=$order["total_price_set"]["shop_money"]["amount"];?></td>
                                      <td data-title="Token"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>                                
                                </table>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then use the $orders variable to create the output table. It is only sowing 250 orders even if I increase the order limit.

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question I know, but perhaps someone can find use of this answer.

There is a way to get all orders by using the `since_id` option in the fetch url and cURL. This way you get 250 (or a number of your choosing below 250 since that is the max number you can fetch in one go) orders, starting with the order id `0`. This will start at the first order. From here, you loop and fetch orders from (using `since_id`) the last order in the previous call. And when the number of orders returned is below the number of orders you fetch in each call, you exit.

Example from a Symfony (5) app:

```
private function getShopifyOrders(): array
    {
        $this->store_name = $this->params->get('app.shopify_store_name');
        $this->api_key = $this->params->get('app.shopify_api_key');
        $this->api_pass = $this->params->get('app.shopify_password');
        $this->api_url = 'https://' . $this->api_key . ':' . $this->api_pass . '@' . $this->store_name;
        $last = 0;
        $allOrders = [];
        while (true) {
            $orders_url = $this->api_url . '/admin/orders.json?limit=250&status=any&since_id=' . $last;
            error_log($orders_url); // Show each call in the log for reference
            $ch = curl_init($orders_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $orders = json_decode($response);

            foreach ( $orders->orders as $order ) {
                $allOrders[] = $order;
                $last = $order->id;
            }

            if ( count( $orders->orders ) < 250 ) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return $allOrders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `page_info`-based paging that Shopify uses. Essentially, you need to look at the headers of the return, and call a new URL from there if applicable (if there are more results available).

Unfortunately this means you can't use `get_file_contents()` since it doesn't allow you to view the headers. Check out curl or another library to make proper HTTP requests.

The relevant Shopify docs are here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/paginated-rest-results